# Building libwebsockets for OP-TEE

Tags: libwebsockets, op-tee

I've been trying to build libwebsockets for OP-TEE running on a TI AM437x HS (an arm platform). I'm using Yocto to build; here's the version string for OP-TEE, which is displayed on boot:

<kbd>I/TC: OP-TEE version: ti2019.05-rc1-dev (gcc version 8.3.0 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36))) #1 Tue Nov 29 17:49:12 UTC 2022 arm</kbd>

I'm using libwebsockets version 4.3.2.

OP-TEE support is documented for libwebsockets:

https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-main/html/md_READMEs_README_build.html#optee

I'm specifying -DLWS_PLAT_OPTEE=1 to CMake, but a number of libwebsockets source files include <kbd>errno.h</kbd>, which is not provided by OP-TEE's minimal libc.  I have tried specifying an additional <kbd>-I</kbd>/<kbd>-isystem</kbd> option to pick up the <kbd>errno.h</kbd> that comes with the toolchain (gcc) but this causes further problems with headers included by it, and I think it should only by used with GNU's libc.

Is OP-TEE still a supported platform for libwebsockets?  If so, how should I resolve the issue with <kbd>errno.h</kbd>?

Thank you for your help!